# Singleton pattern in Dart to make to make shared object

Tags: flutter, dart

What does this code do? There is no such function `_sharedInstance()`, at least I didn't find it. Why the code line `LoadingScreen._sharedInstance();` used again to define `_shared` ? Why to use `factory` there? I.e. this code seems incomprehensible...

```
class LoadingScreen {
  LoadingScreen._sharedInstance();
  static final LoadingScreen _shared = LoadingScreen._sharedInstance();
  factory LoadingScreen.instance() => _shared;
  ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

`_sharedInstance()` is just a private named constructor for `LoadingScreen`, after defining it the class no longer has a default constructor. You can name it anything and it will be private as long as it starts with `_`. Check out [Named Constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors).

`_shared` is used to hold the only instance of `LoadingScreen`, and it gets it's value from invoking the `_sharedInstance()` private named constructor.

If you call `LoadingScreen.instance()` in your code, you will always get the same `object` that is stored in `_shared`. Check out [Factory Constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors).

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to build Singleton. Thanks to Dart's [factory constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors), it's easy to build a singleton:

I suggest it needs a couple of points of explanation. There's the weird syntax `LoadingScreen. _sharedInstance()` that looks like a method call bu actually it's really a constructor definition. There's the `_sharedInstance` name. And there's the nifty language design point that `Dart` lets you start out using an ordinary constructor and then if needed, change it to a factory method without changing all the callers.